# Positions of elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
slist = {3, 5}
```

I want to find the positions of the elements in slist in list. I tried it like this and I dont understand why this is not working:

```
Position[list,slist]
```

Instead I have to use:

```
Position[list, slist[[1]]]
```

and

```
Position[list, slist[[2]]]
```

but this seems tedious and there must be an easier way, which I'm unable to find at the moment :)

Comment: `{3, 5}` is not a pattern that is present at any position within `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or just do a simple mapping:

```
Position[list,#]& /@ slist
```

Should be your Mathematica bread and butter anyways.

Answer (score 7):

```
Position[list, Alternatives @@ slist]
```

> `{{3}, {5}}`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
    Flatten[Table[Position[list, _?(# == slist[[i]] &)], {i, 1, Length[slist]}]]
```